# Login com o google não funciona no apk release Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

No modo de debug, o login funciona normalmente, eu já configurei o SHA1 e também adicionei a permissão da Internet, no modo de depuração ele funciona normalmente, mas quando eu gero o apk final, ele não funciona (abre o painel para eu escolher uma conta, mas depois de selecionar ele não faz nada). O aplicativo precisa estar no google play para funcionar?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver amigo?

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz a publicação no Google Play, a google cria novas assinaturas do app (SHA1) sendo assim, você precisa pegar essa nova sha1 e adicionar no seu projeto no firebase...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espere uns minutinhos e depois instale seu app pelo google play novamente e tente fazer o signin.